# Preload left joined association with a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

```
Class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item_category
end
```

```
Class ItemCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
end
```

Simplified schema:

```
items (id, name, price, item_category_id)
item_categories (id, name, depth(int))
```

Give a list of item ids, I want to load those items.

If the item is in a category of a certain depth (e.g. 2), then I want to additionally preload that category and also all of items in that category, even if they are not in the initial list of item ids.

Closest I've gotten is this, but it preloads all categories, not those that are of a certain depth:

`Item.where(id: IDS).includes(item_category: :items)`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord Query:

```
Item.where(id: IDS).joins(:item_category).where(depth: 2).includes(item_category: :items)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to work. It only returns items that have a category with depth 2. I need all items to be returned.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please let me if that worked for you or not.